# Keep A Bg Image Centered On Screen

Tags: css, html

I want to keep my bg image centered, no matter if the user's monitor is large enough to fit the whole thing or too small to display it all at once.  Similarly, it should remain centered horizontally when a user zooms in using ctrl+.  The issue is best illustrated with images.  Here is a zoomed out shot, which is the correct behavior:

[image]

Here is a zoomed in shot, which is not correct.  The background shows the left margin, and is cut off 100% on the right side.  It should get cut off equally from the left and right sides:

[image]

Finally here is the sample page, so you can play around with zooming in and out yourself:

http://pastehtml.com/view/b3qfjcghu.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to give the container the size of the image, so in fact it never is really 'centered' because it fits neatly at all times.

If you use this for `#container`:

```
width: 100%;
```

Then it will be using the full width of the screen, so that the background will be centered depending on the screen size.

http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/AxzdP/

---

Or, as Artfunkel suggested, you might want to just use the `body` element without any containers.

```
body {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/7JUFb.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: center 0%;
}
```

---

What you could also do is creating a separate container like this:

```
<div id="bgcontainer"></div>
```

with:

```
#bgcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/7JUFb.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: center 0%;
    z-index: -999 /* keep on background so that other elements are above it */
}
```

Comment: You could also ditch `#container`/`#wrap` entirely and use the `body` (or even root `html`) element instead.

Comment: @pimvdb: Thanks, that works but messes up some other things.  Lots of page elments are positioned absolutely wrt the container, so they hit the bg image at the right spots.  This 100% method causes those elements to lose alignment with points on the bg image.  Is there a way I can solve both problems simultaneously?

Comment: You can't both align elements to the background **and** have it disappear off the left edge of the screen. If you really want zooming in to centre on the middle of the page and not the top-left corner you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Ok thanks Art, that answers my 2nd question.  Do you have a link to this js method?

Comment: No, you will need to look one up.